# How map simple object in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

One of my entity, contains a simple object which contains only two attributes.
What is the recommended way of using hibernate/jpa annotation to map this entity.

For example, how to use annotation map Money in entity Report.

```
public class Report{

  private long id;

  private Money amount;

}

public class Money{

  private BigDecimal value;

  private String currency;

}
```

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#embeddables

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve it via this approach:

### General concepts first

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractBaseEntity { 

    public static final long INVALID_OBJECT_ID = -42;

    @Version
    private int version;    

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence-object", sequenceName = "ID_MASTER_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence-object")
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected Long objectID = INVALID_OBJECT_ID;

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    @Override
    public long getObjectID() {
        return objectID;
    }
}
```

### Specific aspects second

```
@Entity
public class Report extends AbstractBaseEntity {

  @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.All)
  private Money amount;

}

@Entity
public class Money extends AbstractBaseEntity {

  @Column(name="value", nullable = false, scale = 3, precision = 13)
  private BigDecimal value;

  @Column(name="currency", nullable = false)
  private String currency;

}
```

This way, you not only manage primary keys of one single entity / database table but for any other type in your domain.

If you require other parameters for the precision of the `BigDecimal` value, you'll might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11898855/2849346). For further details on the `@Version` annotation check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38411240/2849346).

Hope it helps.

Comment: This was my initial idea. But example, apart from Report entity, there are several such entities which contain Money? I think then this will not be the suitable solution.

Comment: This won‘t be a problem. You can refer to `Money` from other/different entities as well. Each time you do, this will just be another relationship which will have a Foreign Key in the corresponding Table in the database. Go try it.